# I receive very different addresses when allocating space

Tags: c++, new-operator, allocation

I am allocating space with `::operator new( sizeof(T) * count)`.

The 1st call returns an address `0x742f30` and the 2nd returns `0x7f2ef0000d60`. I am now confused about the huge difference.

**My question:** Is this normal that the returned addresses can differ that much?

**Update:**

```
SLES 11 SP3 VM on XenServer
gcc 4.9.3
10 GB RAM
```

**Update:**

Because some people suspected a wrong output format. I display the returned address by the `new` command with the same `printf` format. I copied the pointer values to this question by copy and paste and check them twice. They match the output from my Memory Allocator.

Comment: Yes, since the memory actually marks locations as un-allocated, and it may be small block scattered over the whole memory not contagious.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Ideally something that we can compile and play with ourselves.

Comment: That is **very strange**... The difference is approx: **~140TB** - Are you sure you posted the numbers correctly?

Comment: You should'nt need to care. Why do you?

Comment: 1. Show actual code ([mcve]). 2. Which platform, compiler...?

Comment: You did not add the information for the first part of what @Pixelchemist  said.

Comment: I suspect you're printing the addresses with different formats. It's very suspicious that the small address is very close to the upper half of the large address.

Comment: @AlBundy Why won't you post the code so we can see for ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause is that the first object was allocated in the process's initial data segment, but by the time you allocated the second object this filled up. Traditional memory allocators use `sbrk()` to extend the data segment, but some modern memory allocators make use of `mmap()` on `/dev/zero` to create new memory segments. This might allocate its virtual memory in a very distant part of the address space.

Comment: The strange pointer is returned in the 3rd alloc in my own STL Memory Allocator. I don't really think its because the object is filled up. I would like to post the code but its too complex to be posted here. There are dozens of structures involved which are allocated by the Memory Allocator. Anyway, already 3 people voted to close this question so I think it'll be closed anyway. We have now in Central Europe 1:30am and I have to go to bed. The program is now running for hours with lot of threads and it does not crash -> the strange pointers point really to a valid memory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no restrictions regarding the location of the required memory block, as long as the result is a valid memory pointer (i.e. not null), it should be considered fine. But I as a programmer would be surprised to see the response from the memory allocating function being formatted in a different way (in this case with a different number of digits).

Considering that it's your own library, I would at least make sure that it always output the address of the allocated memory in exactly the same format.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that it must be some strange virtualization of the memory by Linux. The output of the addresses are always in the same format. I think the answer from Barmar is very close to the real reason. May be I ask the SuSe IT and they have an answer for this.